# Is it possible to close a position once per trade/order?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading, algorithmic-trading

Is there a way to force Pinescript to execute the strategy.close order only once per order?

I'm trying to implement a strategy.close method that closes only a part of the position and executes the rest to TP/SL.

To this end, I wrote a script to ignore the strategy.close order when the contract size was reduced, but in the end, I wanted to specify the order size method as a percent of equality, so this try was useless.

```
// Define initial position size as 100 and get the current position size
initialPositionSize = 100
currentPositionSize = strategy.position_size

// Check if the current position size is less than 50% of the initial position size
stopCloseOrder = currentPositionSize < initialPositionSize * 0.5

// If there are open trades and the stcDownBreakouts condition is met,
// check if stopCloseOrder is true, and if not, partially exit the long position.
if (strategy.opentrades > 0 and stcDownBreakouts) // Exit condition for a partial exit loss
    if stopCloseOrder
        na
    else
        strategy.close(id='Long Entry', qty_percent = 90, comment='Long Partial Exit')
```

If you have the same experience or any tips, please share them with me. I will appreciate any suggestions from you.

```
//@version=5

strategy('sample', overlay=true, max_labels_count = 500)

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Simple SMA strategt with TP/SL and Schaff Trend partial close
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// sma lenght and TP/SL setting
sma_per = input.int(200, title='SMA Lookback Period', minval=1)
sl_inp = input(4.3, title='Stop Loss %') / 100
tp_inp = input(1.0, title='Take Profit %') / 100

// Getting a SMA
sma = ta.sma(close, sma_per)

// TP/SL calculate 
stop_level = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - sl_inp)
take_level = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + tp_inp)

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Schaff Trend logic
fastLength = input(title='MACD Fast Length', defval=23)
slowLength = input(title='MACD Slow Length', defval=50)
cycleLength = input(title='Cycle Length', defval=10)
d1Length = input(title='1st %D Length', defval=3)
d2Length = input(title='2nd %D Length', defval=3)
src = input(title='Source', defval=close)
upper = input(title='Upper Band', defval=75)
lower = input(title='Lower Band', defval=25)
highlightBreakouts = input(title='Highlight Breakouts ?', defval=true)
macd = ta.ema(src, fastLength) - ta.ema(src, slowLength)
k = nz(fixnan(ta.stoch(macd, macd, macd, cycleLength)))
d = ta.ema(k, d1Length)
kd = nz(fixnan(ta.stoch(d, d, d, cycleLength)))
stc = ta.ema(kd, d2Length)
stc := math.max(math.min(stc, 100), 0)
stcColor1 = stc > stc[1] ? color.green : color.red
stcColor2 = stc > upper ? color.green : stc <= lower ? color.red : color.orange
stcColor = highlightBreakouts ? stcColor2 : stcColor1

// Using security to close when 1H Schaff Trend is Down
ex  = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "60", stc)
stcDownBreakouts = ta.crossunder(ex, 75) ? upper : na


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Getting a Long position
if (ta.crossover(close, sma))
    strategy.entry(id = 'Long Entry', direction = strategy.long)

// Strategy exit for TP/SL
if (strategy.opentrades > 0)
    strategy.exit(id = 'TP/SL Exit', from_entry = 'Long Entry', stop = stop_level, limit = take_level)

// partially exit the long position
if (strategy.opentrades > 0 and stcDownBreakouts)
    strategy.close(id='Long Entry', qty_percent = 90, comment='Long Partial Exit')

// Plot for logic
plot(sma, color=color.new(color.orange, 0), linewidth=2)
plot(stop_level, color=color.new(color.red, 0), style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=2)
plot(take_level, color=color.new(color.green, 0), style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've nailed it.

I don't know why it took so long to sort this out. I hope this approach will help those in need.

```
// Set a boolean variable to trigger partial exit only once per open trade.
var bool partialExitTriggered = false

// If there are open trades and stcDownBreakouts condition is met and partial exit has not been triggered,
// execute a partial exit.
if strategy.opentrades > 0 and stcDownBreakouts and not partialExitTriggered
    strategy.close(id='Long Entry', qty_percent = 90, comment='Long Partial Exit')
    partialExitTriggered := true

// If there are no open trades, reset the partialExitTriggered flag.
if strategy.opentrades == 0
    partialExitTriggered := false
```